# Gulp Notify global success function

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-notify

I'm looking to have gulp-notify success function that is called which I can reuse. I'm using the same format for all of my tasks and would like to clean it up. Here's an example of what I'm doing right now:

```
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    const s = gsize();

    return gulp.src('src/css/main.css')
        .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(s)
        .pipe(notify({
            title: function () {
                return '<%= file.relative %> - ' + s.prettySize;
            },
            onLast: true,
            subtitle: "Successfully Compiled",
            message: "@ Time: <%= options.hour %>:<%= options.minute %>:<%= options.second %> ",
            templateOptions: {
                hour: new Date().getHours(),
                minute: new Date().getMinutes(),
                second: new Date().getSeconds()
            }
        }))
});
```

I'm re-using the same notify function with multiple tasks. I've tried doing something like this, but each attempt throws an error. This particular error is with plumber - `Can't Pipe to Undefined`

```
var onSuccess = function () {
    const s = gsize();
    notify({
        title: function () {
            return '<%= file.relative %> - ' + s.prettySize;
        },
        onLast: true,
        subtitle: "Successfully Compiled",
        message: "@ Time: <%= options.hour %>:<%= options.minute %>:<%= options.second %> ",
        templateOptions: {
            hour: new Date().getHours(),
            minute: new Date().getMinutes(),
            second: new Date().getSeconds()
        }
    })
};

...

gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    const s = gsize();

    return gulp.src('src/css/main.css')
        .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 6 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(s)
        .pipe(onSuccess())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this are appreciated!

**EDIT** After qballers solution, only issue is my gulp-size plugin returning undefined for file sizes:

```
const s = gsize();

// Success Message
var notifyGeneric = {
    title: function () {
        return '<%= file.relative %> - ' + s.prettySize;
    },
    onLast: true,
    subtitle: "Successfully Compiled",
    message: "@ Time: <%= options.hour %>:<%= options.minute %>:<%= options.second %> ",
    templateOptions: {
        hour: date.getHours(),
        minute: date.getMinutes(),
        second: date.getSeconds()
    }
};

...

gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    const s = gsize();

    return gulp.src(srcCssPath + 'main.css')
        .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 6 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(s)
        .pipe(notify(notifyGeneric))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssPath))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this the solution you are gunning for but you can just use object literals to save you code duplications.

```
var notifyGeneric = {
            title: function () {
                return '<%= file.relative %> - ' + this.s.prettySize;
            },
            onLast: true,
            subtitle: "Successfully Compiled",
            message: "@ Time: <%= options.hour %>:<%= options.minute %>:<%= options.second %> ",
            templateOptions: {
                hour: new Date().getHours(),
                minute: new Date().getMinutes(),
                second: new Date().getSeconds()
            },
            s: {}
        };
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    notifyGeneric.s = gsize();
    return gulp.src('src/css/main.css')
        .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(notifyGeneric.s)
        .pipe(notify(notifyGeneric))
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! I had to make the notifyGeneric a var, and also have an instance of my const s = gsize(); as a global variable - after that everything worked as hoped. My file is a lot more clean, thanks!

Comment: Actually - my gulp size is coming in as undefined, any thoughts?

Comment: try this: `.pipe(gsize())`

Comment: should work now, I would try and create a copy of notifyGeneric to modify the s. Also if you still get undefined bind the title function to this.